# Align drawable in textview

Tags: android, textview

I have a textview in my app where android:layout_width is set to fill_parent, android:gravity is "center". Now I would like to have the drawable right next to the textview's text. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use these to set drawables next to the text views, depending on the desired position.
[image]

Comment: These won't work because they'll result in something like this: [link](http://i.imgur.com/oVXcZda.png)

Comment: then just put it inside a LinearLayout that has match_parent width, and set TextView's width to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Using `TextView` alone is quite limited to achieve what you want.

One option is to use a custom layout. You can check out [HorizontalTailLayout](https://github.com/bosphere/Android-HorizontalTailLayout). It's very easy to pickup and throw in your project which should just work.

Another imperfect option is to use RelativeLayout with `android:gravity="fill"`. This will ensure the `ImageView` always stick to the tail of `TextView`. But the drawback is it can't center the content even when wrapped with another layout, because using `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` will stretch `RelativeLayout` all the way to the right.

Example:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="fill">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_lock_lock"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/iv"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! "/>

</RelativeLayout>
```